# Port-Forwarding in Virtual Box

Tags: windows-xp, networking, virtualbox, port-forwarding

I have Virtual Box setup with the following commands:

```
vboxmanage setextradata myVm "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/transfer/HostPort" 50000
vboxmanage setextradata myVm `"VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/transfer/GuestPort" 50000
vboxmanage setextradata myVm "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/transfer/Protocol" TCP
```

On the host machine, the following command times out:

```
telnet localhost 50000
```

What am I doing wrong? The above command does work on the guest machine.

Answer (score 0):

Shutting down and restarting the virtual machine fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

IT. [Have you tried turning it off and on again?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QpmLrz_lSuE)